# How to top align two cell divs within a table div when one cell div contains an absolute positioned div?

Tags: html, css

How do I top align two cell divs within a table div when one cell div contains an absolute positioned div?

In this example the cell div that does not contain an absolutely positioned div gets pushed down.

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
  <div>
    <div>1 11 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="rightIsOnTop">
        <div id="textThatIsBelow">textThatIsBelow</div>
        <div id="textThatIsOnTop">on top</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  font-size:x-large;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#table {
  display: table;
  z-index: 5; /* So that other elements can be put above or below this. */
  position: relative; 
}
#table > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
#table > div > div {
  vertical-align:top;
  min-width:150px;
  margin:10px;
  background:grey;
}
#rightIsOnTop {
  position:relative;
  min-width:80px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#textThatIsBelow {
  position: absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
#textThatIsOnTop {
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
```

This is how they are rendered:

[image]

This is how I would like them to be rendered:

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have an image that show us what you are intended to do?

Comment: I recommended you use flex box model  of css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `vertical-align: top;` to your cell div but not to your content.

It should be

```
#table > div {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:top;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xg7a38yd/1/

Comment: Thank you! I should have figured that out hahaha!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flexbox model of css3 to archieve this:

```
.flexBox {
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

[Here are fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/1jx6g71w/)

You can use flex property on child element to adjust the size of divs.

[Here you can get a complete guide of flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

This rule `#textThatIsOnTop {float: right;}` makes the boxes misaligned.

But making `#textThatIsOnTop` to `position:absolute` sounds more reasonable to me, no floating element is needed. It will also sort out the alignment issue.

```
#textThatIsBelow {
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
#textThatIsOnTop {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
```

Full updated code/demo as follows.

```css
body, html {
    font-size:x-large;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#table {
    display: table;
    z-index: 5; /* So that other elements can be put above or below this. */
    position: relative; 
}
#table > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
#table > div > div {
    vertical-align:top;
    min-width:150px;
    margin:10px;
    background:grey;
}
#rightIsOnTop {
    position:relative;
    min-width:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#textThatIsBelow {
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
#textThatIsOnTop {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div>
        <div>1 11 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="rightIsOnTop">
                <div id="textThatIsBelow">textThatIsBelow</div>
                <div id="textThatIsOnTop">on top</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that your suggestion is good. I think that in this case the advantage of making #textThatIsOnTop float right is that when #rightIsOnTop is less wide the #textThatIsOnTop doesn't get pushed below #textThatIsBelow..

Comment: @JohnCashew In any case, no div will be pushed down in my approach above. demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vr19c6bt/ I also made a demo based on your original code - http://jsfiddle.net/6gsfgr1s/ Either way, you know which works better for you.